# Microsoft reports make table repeat at the same page if there is enough space rdlc

Tags: report, rdlc, tabular

I need help at a report (.rdlc)

The report has table that it's width takes just the half of the width  and the rest of the space is empty.

I need to make the table repeats  at the same page if there is enough space.

For example if the page is like this:

**Page1:**
Serial  Name

1. Mary
2. Lary
3. Carl
4. Jess

**Page2:**
Serial  Name

5. Paul
6. Harry

It should be like this:

**Page1:**
Serial  Name

1. Mary      5.     Paul
2. Lary      6.     Harry
3. Carl
4. Jess